# API call inside ngrx subscriber

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ngrx

Are there any drawbacks / considerations to be made with making API calls inside subscribers? Or is there a preferred approach to this problem? An example:

```
this.store.select('person').subscribe(person => {
    this.http.get(`/tasks/${person.id}`)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(tasks => {
            // Dispatch tasks.update
        });
});
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that calling an HTTP method like that is a good idea.

For example :
 - Your `person` is updated
 - The HTTP request is fired
 - You dispatch an action to save the changes into the store
 - As the store is updated, you'll have another HTTP request launched
 - Etc, etc

You'll end up with a loop and DDOS on your backend.

Instead of that, you should rather dispatch an action `FETCH_PERSON`, catch it with an [Effect](https://github.com/ngrx/effects) and once you get the response in the effect, dispatch another action according to the response (FETCH_PERSON_SUCCESS or FETCH_PERSON_ERROR for example).

Comment: Would I then catch the `FETCH_PERSON_SUCCESS` with an effect and fetch the persons tasks off the back of that?

Comment: You can chain your effects as much as you want without problem. If you don't need to wait for `FETCH_PERSON` in order to  launch your request to get the tasks of that person, you can use the `forkJoin` operator to fire both requests at the same time. It's up to you :)

Comment: Would `FETCH_PERSON_SUCCESS` contain the response from the API call ready for use in the effect which catches it? So if the API call returns for example, `groupId` ... I want to then use this `groupId` in the next effect to do another API call to fetch the group

Comment: The `FETCH_PERSON` just allows you to toggle a flag for UI (`isFetchingPerson: true` for example). Then in your UI you can show a spinner for example. After that, you can catch that within an effect and fire an HTTP call. In this HTTP call, you can manipulate the data from the server. For example, you can normalize your data. From that effect, you can then dispatch another action `FETCH_PERSON_SUCCESS` wich contains normalized data you want to save in your reducer (and you can also toggle the `isFetchingPerson` to false in your reducer).

Comment: You may want to read the source code of those repositories : https://github.com/r-park/soundcloud-ngrx and https://github.com/teropa/harmonics-explorer They are really awesome ;)